# How to use an array of two dimensional float arrays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise, procedural-generation

I've tried using the generic list but my research said that the enumerator for the List could not be reset so that wont do since I need to iterate continuously over a list of float [,].

I essentially want to cache 10 different perlin noise maps that the game loop iterates over. Each perlin map is a float [,]. All maps are of same width and height.

I want to store these in some datastructure that I can continously iterate over, be it generic list or an array:

```
void BuildCache() {
    cache = new float[cacheSize][,];
    for(int i = 0; i < cacheSize; i++) {
        float[,] noiseMap = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap (width, height, seed, noiseScale, octaves, persistence, lacunarity, offset);
        cache [i] [0] = noiseMap;
        offset += speed;
    }
}
```

This results in this error: Assets/Scripts/FogGenerator.cs(51,36): error CS0022: Wrong number of indexes `1' inside [], expected`2'

It seems like a basic thing, in Java I would use a generic list but since I can't reset C#'s generic list I'm at a loss here.

Comment: `cache[i] = noiseMap`, remove `[0]`

Comment: What do you mean you cannot reset the enumerator for a List?

Comment: Arturo how does one declare the cache then? Cause I still get errors.

My definition looks like this: float[][,] cache;

Comment: juharr List<T> in System.Collections.Generic can only be iterated using the enumerator was my belief. This enumerator has no reset implementation and I couldn't create a new enumerator since it started at the end of the list still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In declaration of your array you explicitly declare that *cache* array is an array of multidimensional arrays. Error is in cache[i][0] = noiseMap; because it is similarly to two-dimensional array syntax in C/C++ based languages. You should use cache[i] = noiseMap because then you explicitly nofity compiler that you reference to two dimensional array in this array and write in this some value.

Comment: Make sense, but then how do I define the actual cache? This is the way I was doing it: float[][,] cache;

This produces: Assets/Scripts/FogGenerator.cs(51,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `float[,]' to `float[]'

Comment: Are you sure that you use array_name[index, index] instead of array_name[index][index]? I said you that replace cache[i][0] = noiseMap by cache[i] = noiseMap.

Comment: This works fine. Compare it with your code.
    static void BuildCache()
            {
                var cacheSize = 10;
                var cache = new float[cacheSize][,];
                for (int i = 0; i < cacheSize; i++)
                {
                    float[,] noiseMap = {{2.3f,4.5f},{2.3f,4.5f}};
                    cache[i] = noiseMap;
                }
            }

Comment: @shfire: I thought about the same